# Spring Securitiy jdbc-user-service not authenticating - bad credentials

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-jdbc

Spring Security is giving me fits, I cannot get around the authentication error.  Here is my config:

```
<beans:bean id='bCryptPasswordEncoder' class='org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder'/>
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
      <jdbc-user-service
          data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query="select emplid as USERNAME ,password as PASSWORD,'true' AS ENABLED from app_user where emplid=?"
          authorities-by-username-query="select u.emplid, p.name from app_user u inner join app_user_app_permissions auap ON auap.app_users = u.id inner join app_permission p on p.id = auap.app_permissions where u.emplid =?" />
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
```

I'm creating my encoded password with:

```
String password = "p4ssword";
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

I've verified that the correct user/password are in the database, and that the query that fetches them runs.

Any idea why this does not work, it's driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

If the users-by-username-query works fine then the first thing to check is the second query. The one returning roles/authorities assigned to a user. For a login attempt to be successful a user must have at least one role returned by the authorities-by-username-query.

To test it you can use a query like this: "select u.emplid, 'USER' from app_user u WHERE u.emplid=?".

If it still doesn't work then your best choice is to set logging level to DEBUG and see what Spring is exactly doing step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in secoand query means authorities-by-username query that should be only username and role not email,name etc.

```
`<bean id="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="ds"
        users-by-username-query="select user_name,user_password,enabled,user_email from user where user_name=?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select user_name,user_role from user_role where user_name=?"
        />
        <s
        <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" ref="bcryptEncoder"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>`
```